# why doesn't dash grammar accept for loop with a non-empty linebreak grammar symbol - is this a dash bug?

Tags: shell, dash-shell

Under `dash` shell, I see

```
for foo
>in
dash: Syntax error: "in" unexpected (expecting "do")
```

The POSIX shell grammar at

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02

has

`for_clause       :`(...)

`| For name linebreak in` (...)

```
newline_list     :              NEWLINE
                 | newline_list NEWLINE
                 ;
linebreak        : newline_list
                 | /* empty */
```

so `linebreak` does not have to be empty, but could be newline(s).  Then why do I see that error?  Is this a `dash` bug?

`bash` does accept this example, but clearly the example has nothing to do with any "bash-ism", it is just basic POSIX shell syntax, common to both `dash` and `bash`.

Comment: What version of `dash` do you use (what platform does it come with)? I don't see this behavior in v0.5.8.

Comment: I can duplicate the error with `for foo <nl> in <nl> ...` in 0.5.8.

Comment: @mklement0 0.5.7, so yes, looks like that is a bug in that version.  Unfortunately for me, I have to use 0.5.7 ... Because 0.5.8 is _too_strict_ :)  - it fixed some other bug, which a script relies on, and I can't change that script.  That's why I cannot upgrade to 0.5.8.  Auwe!  as Hawaiians would say.